# How to refresh a form in dynamics ax7/365

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations

I have two forms **FormA** (*SalesTable*) and **FormB** (*SalesAvailableDlvDates*).

From **FormA**, I will click a button to open up **FormB**.

Then I will click another button in **FormB** which will bring me back to **FormA**.

What I want to happen is, when I click the button in **FormB** I would like to refresh **FormA** as I get back to that form.

Is that possible?

This is the button in **FormB** where when I click it, I'll go back to **FormA**:

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(SalesAvailableDlvDates, TransferToConfirmedButton), FormControlEventType::Clicked)]
    public static void TransferToConfirmedButton_OnClicked(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `FormControl sender` - the form control raising the event.

Would the following work for you?

```
FormRun formRun = sender.formRun();      // get the caller form
FormObjectSet ds = formRun.dataSource(); // caller form's datasource
ds.reread();
ds.refresh();                            // refresh values in the caller form
//or ds.research(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example,

- **FormA** is LogisticsPostalAddressGrid (or any other form).
- **FormB** is LogisticsLocationDefault

On clicking on the OK button on the LogisticsLocationDefault (FormB) form, the data on the LogisticsPostalAddressGrid (FormA) will be refreshed.

Please find an example for the form LogisticsLocationDefault below.

```
/// <summary>
///     Valery Moskalenko, 12/20/2021
/// </summary>
class MyLogisticsLocationDefault_FormEventHandler
{
    /// <summary>  
    ///     Refresh caller form (LogisticsPostalAddressGrid) on clicking the OK button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_sender">FormControl</param>
    /// <param name="_e">FormControlEventArgs</param>
    [FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(LogisticsLocationDefault, OK), FormControlEventType::Clicked),
     SuppressBPWarningAttribute('BPParameterNotUsed', 'This is expected and can be skipped')]
    public static void OK_OnClicked(FormControl _sender, FormControlEventArgs _e)
    {
        FormRun formRun = _sender.formRun();

        if (formRun)
        {
            FormRun callerFormRun = formRun.args().caller();

            if (callerFormRun)
            {
                #Task
                callerFormRun.task(#taskRefresh);
            }
        }
    }

}
```